# Find day light saving time for a given year using php

Tags: php, timezone, dst

i would like to know is there a anyway we can find the `DST(day light saving time)` for the given year.

Comment: "The given year"? Each year has a DST period and one without... (notwithstanding countries that switched in recent history).

Comment: How do you mean "for a given year"? DST may vary from country-to-country.

Comment: i would like to calculate it for the year 2012 and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `I` parameter in the standard `date` function to get a 0/1 flag if DST.

[PHP Manual Date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

For the United States daylight savings time begins the Second Sunday of March and ends on the First Sunday of November. So...

```
<?php  
$remove_hour = strtotime("Second Sunday March 0");  
$add_hour = strtotime("First Sunday November 0");  

$time  = time();  

if( $time >= $remove_hour && $time < $add_hour )  
{  
    var_dump("Lost an hour");  
}  
else  
{  
    var_dump("Gained an hour");  
}
?>
```

Although as far as I know this doesn't change every year? Not sure what you mean by that?